# Changes to how iOS8 Safari handles readonly input fields

Tags: javascript, ios8, mobile-safari

I'm running into issues with how iOS 8 handles readonly on input fields compared to how iOS 7.1.2 handled them.

In iOS 7.1.2, selecting a readonly drop list element would simply expand the list and allow you to select an item from that list. Now in iOS 8, Safari will now allow a cursor inside this drop listwhich prevent the drop list from opening.  I have to touch another element to shift focus, and then touch back on the drop list to expand it.

I made these elements readonly to sidestep that issue, but now that doesn't work anymore either.

Is there a way I can get the old behavior back, or prevent a cursor some other way?